# SSRS 2012 64bit pointing to a 64bit Oracle database (12c) error

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

From my development environment (Visual Studio) I can run reports however when deployed I get the error.

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to X
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

All I can think of is due to the fact that there is an Oracle 32 and 64 bit client SSRS is picking up the 32 bit version.

Is there a way I can debug SSRS to show me exactly what version of the oracle client it is using for the database connection?

Cheers
Jeremy

Comment: Have a look at [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals

Comment: I am receiving the same error... were you able to resolve the issue. I do not believe it has anything to do with 32 vs 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

As you implied the issue is with the Oracle Client. Unfortunately Microsoft has no intention of resolving the issue with versions prior to SSRS 2016. The only current work around for prior versions is to use SOAP to access the Oracle Stored procedure as the datasource or update to 2016.